# append to unordered list (ul) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

```
<ul id="list">
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="int1" />int1</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="int2" />int2</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="int3" />int3</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="int4" />int4</li>
</ul>
```

this

```
$("#list").append('<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="55" id="int55" />int55</li>');
```

make:

```
<ul id="list">
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="int1" />int1</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="int2" />int2</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="int3" />int3</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="int4" />int4</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="55" id="int55" />int55</li>
</ul>
```

how can i make for example

```
<ul id="list">
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="int1" />int1</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="int2" />int2</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="55" id="int55" />int55</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="int3" />int3</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="int4" />int4</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul id="list">
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="int1" />int1</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="int2" />int2</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="int3" />int3</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="55" id="int55" />int55</li>
<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="int4" />int4</li>
</ul>
```

?

Comment: So you want to insert a child of `<ul>`, not at the end, but somewhere in the middle? Is that your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors in jquery are realy powerful

```
 $("#list > li:eq(2)").after('<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="55" id="int55" />int55</li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#int2").parent().after('<li><input name="int[]" type="checkbox" value="55" id="int55" />int55</li>');
```

This inserts the new element after the parent of the element with `id` "int2". See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/rkWDR/1/).

You need to use `parent` because otherwise the new element will be inserted inside the same `li` element as the `input` with the given `id` (although your question title is (now *was*) misleading... in your examples you want the new element added as a new `li`, but your title says "append to `li`".)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after()` method. eg.

```
$('li').eq(2).after('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you'll want to do something like this:

```
var pos = 2; // Will insert before the second <li>
$('#list :nth-child(' + pos + ')').before('<li>NEW</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) will suffice.  [Look](http://jsfiddle.net/kUvGX/) :)